# Choose execution order of post-build steps in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to execute two jobs, one after the other is Jenkins as post-build steps. For this I'm using the Flexible publish plug-in. The plug-in description say that you can "Select the execution order of the publishers", but everything I have tried just run the jobs in paralell. Is there anyway to run the in serial?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear to me if you want to run two projects or two steps, I will provide my workaround for both of them.

Let's assume you want to run two separate projects when you current build is finished, you can achieve that by defining a dependency of the projects setting the one project to be a downstream of the previous project. You can do that easily by choosing on the Post-build Action 'Build other Projects'.

On the other hand for small tasks/steps which you want to execute in the current project sequentially, I often use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and I define the conditions for the tasks I want to run in sequence.